# Is there any method that convert a concave problem into convex problem?

Tags: optimization

I have an optimization problem of the form:

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
x_2 \rightarrow \min,
\\
\text{subject to:} \\
f_1(x) \leq 0, \\
f_2(x) \leq 0,
\end{cases}
\end{align}

with $x= (x_1,x_2)^T$ as the optimization variable.

Here, $f_1(\cdot)$ is a convex function. But $f_2(\cdot)$ is a concave function.

Explicitly, $f_2(x)$ is of the form:
\begin{align}
f_2(x) = 2(D-x_1-2R)+\beta \frac{D^2-x_1^2+2DR-2Rx_1}{4R}-x_2,
\end{align}
with $D,R,\beta$ constant.

How to convert $f_2(x)$ to a convex function? Is there any method that do such a modification?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Tina, I edited your question, maybe you could make sure that the form of $f_2$ is still correct.

Comment: yes.It is still correct.Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.  If $f_2$ was convex, any local optimum will be a global optimum.  This is not true if $f_2$ is concave: there may be many local optima.  So these are two quite different types of problem, and in general problems with non-convex constraints are much harder.  There is no way to "transform" your way out of it.